# Why does GitHub not allow to color texts in .md files?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

So recently I was using [Azure DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server) for projects and I really liked the wiki there.

However, a week ago for a university project I had to use GitHub directly, where I realized that even basic formatting options are missing. One of the missing option that hit me hard was that I can't even color texts.

In Azure DevOps you can color texts like this:

```html
<font color="red">Please Note that this is a work in progress repository!</font>
```

After a little bit of searching on the Internet I only found half solutions like use a picture, etc., and GitHub issues that were closed without real explanations.

Why does GitHub not allow us to color our texts? Is there a technical reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, GitHub doesn't allow most transformations on text in wikis, READMEs, and rendered HTML.  There are a couple reasons for this.

One, many transformations can allow overflowing regions of the page or other techniques that could possibly spoof content.  This includes many `font` tags and many types of CSS.  Because spoofing or attempting to modify other page content is a security issue, most of those UI tweaks are disallowed.  I suspect, in fact, that GitHub strips `font` tags altogether for this reason.

Two, GitHub wants the page to be legible and readable for all users.  Rendered pages need to be able to be read on a wide variety of devices, with a wide variety of font sizes, by pretty much every user.  Even if you can read light grey on white, many people cannot, and for accessibility reasons, changing colors arbitrarily isn't a good idea.  GitHub is required by law to be accessible.

Three, if people can write content in pages that is unreadable, say white on white, then they can create a spam and abuse problem.  This means that people can try to host content that links to spammy sites and hide it from view, benefiting from the fact that GitHub is a popular site.

Four, letting people change styling and colors presents potential problems.  Even if your styling were unproblematic for all of the other reasons above, if GitHub wanted to introduce a dark mode, then letting people arbitrarily color their wikis would prevent that from being a possibility.