# HMTL formatted jupyter markdown doesn't show properly when I upload notebook on GitHub

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, markdown

This is an example line from my notebook:

```
## <font color=DodgerBlue><i>3.6.2 Simple Linear Regression</i></font>
The <font color=tomato><b>Boston</font> data set has <font color=tomato><b>medv</b></font> column which is the median house value for 506 neighborhoods around Boston.
```

it works fine in my notebook environment but when I upload it to the GitHub repository it shows [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMZd8.jpg):

Comment: Is this in the GitHub web interface?

Comment: Yes it's on github.com when you go into the repository

Answer (score 0):

In general, GitHub's rendering of various document formats doesn't handle any sort of colors and it only permits limited styling.  That's the case for several reasons, including [security, accessibility, abuse prevention, and future extensibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783053/why-github-does-not-allow-to-color-texts-in-md-files/60783169).

Additionally, GitHub doesn't support every feature in every document format.  The web interface is designed to provide a reasonable rendering of documents when that's possible, but it can't implement every feature, so it's expected that if you need a fully featured document, you'll clone the repository and render it using an appropriate tool.